# Android Parsing Json giving an empty string

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to parse a Json response coming from url:

The response is the following:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "message": "Request Successfull",
  "messagetitle": "Success",
  "show": "false",
  "goback": "false",
  "marriages": [
    {
      "marriagenum": "8",
      "marriage_from": "2015-09-04",
      "marriage_to": "2015-09-04",
      "planner": {
        "id": "9",
        "fbid": "67656767676767",
        "name": "dsds sd",
        "imageurl": "https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/545435544334423243\/picture?type=large"
      },
      "groom": {
        "id": "1",
        "fbid": "4333334344343",
        "name": "X Y",
        "imageurl": "http:\/\/www.page.com\/mobileapp\/uploads\/profilepics\/fdsfdsfdsfdsfds.jpg"
      },
      "bride": {
        "id": "12",
        "fbid": "455445454",
        "name": "dada ssd",
        "imageurl": "https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/2343444344343432323\/picture?type=large"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to get the "imageurl" of the "planner","groom" and "bride".

Here is my java code:

```
 HttpEntity entity2 = response.getEntity();
 String data2 = EntityUtils.toString(entity2);
 JSONObject jsono2 = new JSONObject(data2);
JSONArray jarray2 = jsono2.getJSONArray("marriages");

      for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
   {
  JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
  JSONObject planner_object = object.getJSONObject("planner");
  JSONObject groom_object = object.getJSONObject("groom");
  JSONObject bride_object = object.getJSONObject("bride");
  planner_image=planner_image+planner_object.optString("imageurl")+"\n";
  String groom_image=groom_image+groom_object.optString("imageurl")+"\n";
  String bride_image=bride_image+bride_object.optString("imageurl")+"\n";
   }

Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),planner_image,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I'm getting the planner_image as an empty string.
Any help please ?

Comment: Where are you defining `l`? Try replacing `l` with `jarray.length()`. Also, where is `planner_image` defined?

Comment: l is the jarray.length() and planner_image is a public string variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the question seems to be incomplete. For example, how is `jArray` initialized? Did you mean to use jArray2 in your loop? In any case, the following below works:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Test {

static String test = "{\n  \"status\": \"success\",\n  \"message\": \"Request Successfull\",\n  \"messagetitle\": \"Success\",\n  \"show\": \"false\",\n  \"goback\": \"false\",\n  \"marriages\": [\n    {\n      \"marriagenum\": \"8\",\n      \"marriage_from\": \"2015-09-04\",\n      \"marriage_to\": \"2015-09-04\",\n      \"planner\": {\n        \"id\": \"9\",\n        \"fbid\": \"67656767676767\",\n        \"name\": \"dsds sd\",\n        \"imageurl\": \"https:\\/\\/graph.facebook.com\\/545435544334423243\\/picture?type=large\"\n      },\n      \"groom\": {\n        \"id\": \"1\",\n        \"fbid\": \"4333334344343\",\n        \"name\": \"X Y\",\n        \"imageurl\": \"http:\\/\\/www.page.com\\/mobileapp\\/uploads\\/profilepics\\/fdsfdsfdsfdsfds.jpg\"\n      },\n      \"bride\": {\n        \"id\": \"12\",\n        \"fbid\": \"455445454\",\n        \"name\": \"dada ssd\",\n        \"imageurl\": \"https:\\/\\/graph.facebook.com\\/2343444344343432323\\/picture?type=large\"\n      }\n    }\n  ]\n}";

public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {

    JSONObject jArray= new JSONObject(test);
    JSONArray marrArray = jArray.getJSONArray("marriages");

    for (int i = 0 ; i < marrArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object = marrArray.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject planner_object = object.getJSONObject("planner");
        JSONObject groom_object = object.getJSONObject("groom");
        JSONObject bride_object = object.getJSONObject("bride");
        System.out.println(planner_object.optString("imageurl"));
        System.out.println(groom_object.optString("imageurl"));
        System.out.println(bride_object.optString("imageurl"));
   }
}
```

Std out:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/545435544334423243/picture?type=large
http://www.page.com/mobileapp/uploads/profilepics/fdsfdsfdsfdsfds.jpg
https://graph.facebook.com/2343444344343432323/picture?type=large
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I see the problem here:

```
JSONArray jarray2 = jsono2.getJSONArray("marriages");
```

You are accessing the marriages JSONArray, and then here:

```
JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
```

You are getting the object from jarray (where the marriages JSONArray is called jarray2?)

So, all objects you are trying to access (planner_object, groom_object, bride_object) are all in **jarray2**, but you are trying to get them from **jarray**.

Also, you are using [optString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString(java.lang.String)) and the documentation says:

> Returns the value mapped by name if it exists, coercing it if necessary, or the empty string if no such mapping exists.

So this tells me you are definitely accessing the wrong object to get the strings, since they are returning empty.

Change your code to:

```
JSONObject object = jarray2.getJSONObject(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solutions seem right, but have changed some codes, this should work.

```
JSONObject jsono2 = new JSONObject(data2);
JSONArray jarray2 = jsono2.getJSONArray("marriages");

  for(int i=0;i<jarray2.length(); i++)
  {

JSONObject object = jarray2.getJSONObject(i);
JSONObject planner_object = object.getJSONObject("planner");
JSONObject groom_object = object.getJSONObject("groom");
JSONObject bride_object = object.getJSONObject("bride");
String planner_image = planner_image + planner_object.getString("imageurl")+"\n";
String groom_image = groom_image + groom_object.getString("imageurl")+"\n";
String bride_image = bride_image + bride_object.getString("imageurl")+"\n";

 }
```

I have changed the `optString` to `getString` and some basic codes

Answer (score -1):

Your for loop should be look like that,

```
for(int i=0;i<jarray2.length();i++)
```